# Trying to make a Formik multistep with validation. How can I validate fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to make a field validation in a formik. The problem is that I made a multi-step form, my approach is that I made an array of components and I use them based on pages[state] and I don't know how to send props to that. 
I want to validate the field to take only two digit numbers, and to show a error message if it doesn't

```
const SignUp = () => {
  const state = useSelector((state: RootState) => state);
  console.log("state", state);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" }}
      onSubmit={values => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }, 500);
      }}
      render={({ errors, touched, isValidating }) => (
        <Form>
          <div>{pages[state]}</div>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(decrement());
            }}
          >
            Prev
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              pages.length - 1 <= state
                ? console.log("No more pages")
                : dispatch(increment());
            }}
          >
            Next
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />
  );
};

const Page2 = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        What is your <span id="idealWeightText">ideal weight</span> that you
        want to reach?
      </h1>
      <Input
        name={"firstName"}
        htmlFor={"firstName"}
        type={"number"}
        validation={validateKilograms}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const Input: React.FC<FieldProps> = ({
  name,
  onChange,
  htmlFor,
  type,
  validation,
  placeholder
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={name}>
        <Field
          type={type}
          name={name}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          validate={validation}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        kg
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi you could also use a `validate` function and trigger it `onChange` of your fields see in the docs https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#field-level-validation

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called Yup, That You can use, You will get freedom to set conditional validations.

Yup is best suited with formik for validations.

After Every step You can enable a flag and set the validation accordingly.

Also I would suggest you to use withFormik. Instead of formik because there you can  make a separate file for validations and can give its path. So that will also improve your folder structure.

Comment: any idea where to start with learning this ? some 2019 info I mean ?

Comment: I am pasting a sample, which will help you to understand in a better way, But also you need to follow the official documentation, I am only sharing the High level workflow